# How to create facet plot for multiple distributions fit using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data_frame(
  genes = paste("Gene_",letters[0:10],sep=""),
  X = abs(rnorm(10, 0, 1)),
  Y = abs(rnorm(10, 0, 2)),
  Z = abs(rnorm(10, 0, 4)))

df
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>     genes         X          Y         Z
#>     <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  Gene_a 0.6264538 3.02356234 3.6759095
#> 2  Gene_b 0.1836433 0.77968647 3.1285452
#> 3  Gene_c 0.8356286 1.24248116 0.2982599
#> 4  Gene_d 1.5952808 4.42939977 7.9574068
#> 5  Gene_e 0.3295078 2.24986184 2.4793030
#> 6  Gene_f 0.8204684 0.08986722 0.2245150
#> 7  Gene_g 0.4874291 0.03238053 0.6231820
#> 8  Gene_h 0.7383247 1.88767242 5.8830095
#> 9  Gene_i 0.5757814 1.64244239 1.9126002
#> 10 Gene_j 0.3053884 1.18780264 1.6717662
```

And this one that estimate the parameter for each non-gene column above:

```r
alldf <- structure(list(var = c("X", "Y", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"), mod_est_mean = c(0.649790620181318, 
  1.65651567796795, 2.78544973796179, -0.594317687136244, -0.116217058012966, 
  0.518234267967891), mod_est_sd = c(0.37898907459421, 1.27340261798159, 2.38265470031565, 
  0.583177003946691, 1.49404482354149, 1.14803152575931), logLik = c(-4.48690631961252, 
  -16.6063107770219, -22.8715381956973, -2.85356316184894, -17.0420856382274, 
  -20.7522156015569), dist_name = c("normal", "normal", "normal", "lognormal", 
  "lognormal", "lognormal")), .Names = c("var", "mod_est_mean", "mod_est_sd", 
  "logLik", "dist_name"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame"))
alldf
#>   var mod_est_mean mod_est_sd     logLik dist_name
#> 1   X    0.6497906  0.3789891  -4.486906    normal
#> 2   Y    1.6565157  1.2734026 -16.606311    normal
#> 3   Z    2.7854497  2.3826547 -22.871538    normal
#> 4   X   -0.5943177  0.5831770  -2.853563 lognormal
#> 5   Y   -0.1162171  1.4940448 -17.042086 lognormal
#> 6   Z    0.5182343  1.1480315 -20.752216 lognormal
```

What I want to do is to create facet plot for X,Y,Z. Each facet contain 3 lines (actual data, normal fit, lognormal fit).

I can do it just for X

```r
#Plot just one distribution (df$X)
x <- df$X
den <- density(x)
df_x <- data.frame(x = den$x, y = den$y)
df_x
norm_param <- alldf %>% filter(var=="X", dist_name=="normal")
lognorm_param <- alldf %>% filter(var=="X", dist_name=="lognormal")
ggplot(df_x, aes(x = x,y = y)) +
   geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=df_x$x, y=dnorm(x=df_x$x, mean=norm_param$mod_est_mean, sd=norm_param$mod_est_sd) ), color="red", size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(x=df_x$x, y=dnorm(x=log(df_x$x), mean=lognorm_param$mod_est_mean, sd=lognorm_param$mod_est_sd) ), color="blue", size = 1) +
  theme_classic()
  # And how can I include legend for 3 lines?
```

[image]

Black (actual data), red (normal fit), blue(lognormal fit)

But how can I do it for facet?

Comment: To get you on the right track, try passing the unfiltered data frame into `ggplot`, rather than filtering it first. Then get your 3 lines by adding `col=dist_name` into `aes()`, and your facets by adding `+ facet_grid(.~var)` to the overall plot creation. Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it. Basically you want to pass one long data frame to `ggplot` whenever possible. Make the long data frame from your data. I'll do it here with `lapply` doing your calculations for each row of `alldf` to get the 3 separate datasets you want, labeling them with what they represent, then binding those datasets together into one long one.

```
df <- lapply( X = seq_len( nrow( alldf ) ),
              FUN = function(x) {
                  df <- data.frame(
                      x = df_x$x,
                      y = df_x$y
                  )
                  if( alldf$dist_name[x] == "normal" ) {
                      df$d_norm <- dnorm( x = df_x$x, mean = alldf$mod_est_mean[x], sd = alldf$mod_est_sd[x] )
                  } else if( alldf$dist_name[x] == "lognormal" ) {
                      df$d_norm <- dnorm( x = log( df_x$x ), mean = alldf$mod_est_mean[x], sd = alldf$mod_est_sd[x] )
                  }
                  df$var <- alldf$var[x]
                  df$dist_name <- alldf$dist_name[x]
                  df
              } )
df <- do.call( rbind, df )

head( df )
           x           y     d_norm var dist_name
1 -0.3642300 0.002889036 0.02936093   X    normal
2 -0.3593232 0.003142633 0.03039330   X    normal
3 -0.3544164 0.003412660 0.03145670   X    normal
4 -0.3495096 0.003697873 0.03255185   X    normal
5 -0.3446028 0.004015857 0.03367948   X    normal
6 -0.3396959 0.004349725 0.03484033   X    normal
```

Now that you've got some tidy data, you can pass it to `ggplot`, telling it to make the colours according to the `dist_name` by putting that in as an `aes` parameter, and telling it to `facet` by the `var` volumn values (in this case as the "columns" of that "grid")

```
ggplot( df ) +
    geom_point( aes( x = x, y = y ), size = 3 ) +
    geom_line( aes( x = x, y = d_norm, col = dist_name ), size = 1 ) +
    theme_classic() +
    facet_grid( . ~ var )
```

[image]

Comment: I think you have to treat lognormal differently see my OP, especially this line `  geom_line(aes(x=df_x$x, y=dnorm(x=log(df_x$x), mean=lognorm_param$mod_est_mean, sd=lognorm_param$mod_est_sd) ), color="blue", size = 1)`

Comment: Ah I see, I'd missed that. I've added a condition in the loop to account for it now, does that look like what you're after? The three plots look to match the outputs using your code (changing "X" to "Y" and "Z" respectively)

Comment: Note I've used base R for everything except the plot call here. You can certainly do this with `tidyverse` tools if you prefer though.

Answer (score 0):

Few years late, but in case someone else comes here looking how to do this the following works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(value))+
    geom_density(aes(color = 'emprical'), size = 1)+
    stat_function(fun = ~ dnorm(.x,
                                MASS::fitdistr(.x, 'normal')$estimate[[1]],
                                MASS::fitdistr(.x, 'normal')$estimate[[2]]),
                  aes(color = 'Normal'))+
    stat_function(fun = ~ dlnorm(.x, 
                                 MASS::fitdistr(.x, 'log-normal')$estimate[[1]], 
                                 MASS::fitdistr(.x, 'log-normal')$estimate[[2]]),
                  aes(color = 'Log-Normal'))+
    theme_minimal()+
    facet_wrap(name~., scale = 'free')
```

Which generates the following plot:
[image]